# What is VM###_main.dart.js?

Tags: flutter

While developing a Flutter web app I came across a problem appearing only in ***release mode***.

I use a provider containing a flag indicating when a particular screen is active: I set it to true during initState and to false on deactivation.

I discovered that leaving the page seems to act on main.dart.js but not on VM1141.main.dart.js (the number changes at every refresh of the page).

[image: console.log]

In this image you can see that switching the field to false only appears in main.dart.js.

**What is this VM###.main.dart.js?**

**Why doesn't it receive the command when deactivating the screen, while main.dart.js does?**

Answer (score 1):

I've also encountered this issue.

I solved this issue by removing

```
<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

in my web/index.html